# Including a variable into an url string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering how to insert the imageId number into the url string, I got confused when there's a string inside a string.

```js
const imageId = 13935764;

switchBackground.onclick = function(){
  setbg.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/'+imageId+'pexels-photo-13366951.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-kwnos-iv-13366951.jpg&fm=jpg')";
}
```

Comment: You'll need to fix your quotes: `"url('…"+imageId+"…')"`

Comment: Better yet, use a template string `\`url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/${imageId}pexels-photo-13366951.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-kwnos-iv-13366951.jpg&fm=jpg')\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use template literals (backticks)

```
switchBackground.onclick = function(){
  setbg.style.backgroundImage = `url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/${imageId}pexels-photo-13366951.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-kwnos-iv-13366951.jpg&fm=jpg')`;
}
```

The issue is that the double-quotes is treating the entire string as a literal and not adding in the `imageId`.